# From NetCDF file to csv by Python

Tags: python, file, csv, shapefile, netcdf

Sorry for my bad English.
I am in an internship, I never have used Python before this.
I need to extract data from a NetCDF file.

I already have created a loop which creates a DataFrame, but when I try to extract this DataFrame I only have 201 values on 41000.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date

nc = Dataset('Q:/QGIS/2011001.nc', 'r')

chla = nc.variables['chlorophyll_a'][0]
lons = nc.variables['lon'][:]
lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
time = nc.variables['time'][:]
nlons=len(lons)
nlat=len(lat)
```

The first loop give me the 41000 values in ArcGIS python console

```
for i in range(0,nlat) :
dla = {'lat':lat[i],'long':lons,'chla':chla[i]}
z = pd.DataFrame(dla)
print (z)

z.to_csv('Q:/QGIS/fichier.csv', sep =',', index= True)
```

But when I do the to.csv I only get 201 values in the csv file.

```
for y in range(0,nlat):
q[y].to_csv('Q:/QGIS/fichier.csv', sep =',', index= True)

for i in range(0,nlat):
    dlo ={'lat':lat[i],'long':lons,'chla':chla[i]}
    q[y] = pd.DataFrame(dlo)
print(q)
```

I hope that you will have an answer to solve this, moreover if you have any script to extract values for create an shp file I would be very grateful if you can share it!

Best regards

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your first attempt in Python? Well, it's not too bad, by far. The problem may lie in what you loop on. Your first loop, yielding 41,000 values, uses `nlat`. Your second loop uses `nlons`. Is that intentional, or would you need `nlat` there as well?

Comment: It as my mistake, i edited this ! Thank you :D

Comment: I need a CSV wich contain the for each couple of lat/long a value of Chla, and there is 41 000 values :D I dont know if i am clear ?